# Can I Hook Into the TinyMCE Insert/Edit Link Button to Use Shortlink For Post?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, actions, tinymce

The idea here is to be able to use the Link button to search through posts as usual, but, once selected, use the shortlink (with something like `wp_get_shortlink();`) instead of the permalink:

`<a href="http://example.com/?p=1234">The Link</a>`

Not sure if it would be easier to add this function to the existing button or add a new button with this dedicated behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the *link dialog*, then we can modify the *permalinks* with the [`wp_link_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_link_query/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_link_query', function( $results )
{
    foreach( $results as &$result )
        $result['permalink'] = wp_get_shortlink( $result['ID'] );

    return $results;
} );
```

where we use [`wp_get_shortlink()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_shortlink) to get the *short links*.

Answer (score 0):

You'd go with new button, which will place i.e. `[post_shrtl]` anywhere in content area (or you can add that phrase manually without button). And then just add this code in `funcitons.php`:

```
add_shortcode('post_shrtl', function($atts){
    return $GLOBALS['post']->guid;
});
```